# Nomad Variables are not accessible in Job specification

Tags: hashicorp, nomad

I am new to Nomad and trying to figure out how can I make a use of variables in Nomad using template and I am struggling to figure out how that can be achieved.

Here is my partial job specification which uses template write variable in a `${NOMAD_SECRETS_DIR}` and access it as environment variable

```
    template {
            destination = "${NOMAD_SECRETS_DIR}/env.vars"
            env         = true
            data        = <<EOH
    {{ range nomadVarList "nomad/jobs@arch-team" }}
      {{ . }}
    {{ end }}
    EOH
         }
```

Where arch-team is the namespace in which variables are created as seen below
[image]

Here are my two variables:
[image]

Here is my job specification where I am trying to access those variables (`role_id` and `temp_environment`) in env stanza.

```
job "email-api" {
  datacenters = ["dc1"]
  node_pool = "rhel-8x"
  namespace = "arch-team"

  group "api" {
     scaling {
      min     = 1
      max     = 10
      enabled = true
    }

    update {
        max_parallel      = 3
        health_check      = "checks"
        min_healthy_time  = "10s"
        healthy_deadline  = "5m"
        progress_deadline = "10m"
        auto_revert       = true
        auto_promote      = true
        canary            = 1
        stagger           = "30s"
    }

    spread {
    attribute = "${node.unique.id}"
    }

    network {
        port  "http"{
            to = 80
        }
    }

    service {
        name = "emailhandler-api"
        port = "http"
    }

    task "server" {
        template {
            destination = "${NOMAD_SECRETS_DIR}/env.vars"
            env         = true
            data        = <<EOH
                {{ range nomadVarList "nomad/jobs@arch-team" }}
                {{ . }}
                {{ end }}
                EOH
         }

         env {
            environment    = "${NOMAD_PORT_http}"
            NODE_IP = "${NOMAD_IP_http}"
            ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "${temp_environment}"
            HashiVaultRoleId_arch = "${role_id}"
          }
          driver = "docker"
          config {
            image = "myregistry/sr.emailhandler.webapi:0.1.22"
            ports = ["http"]
            force_pull = true
          }
        }
    }
}
```

I exported `$NOMAD_TOKEN` which is really a management token… When I plan and run job, it just waits and then fails.

I just don’t know how to check what might have happened while trying to get those variables.
Is there anything I need to do to read these variables? As I mentioned, I am running job using my nomad_token which is a management token.

Also if someone can tell me how to access the detailed logs of a job I submitted. I tried `nomad alloc logs <allocation_id>` but it only prints logs that my job writes on console. I don’t see any logs from Nomad.

I will appreciate help in this regards. I am struggling from last couple of days with this.

**EDIT 1**

Based on suggestion from @KamilCuk, I created workload ACL Policy that looks something like this (hcl file called `jobs-variables-policy.hcl`):

```
namespace "arch-team" {
  variables {
    path "*" {
      capabilities = ["read"]
    }
  }
}
```

I then applied policy as follows:

```
nomad acl policy apply -namespace arch-team -job email-api email-api-policy ./jobs-variables-policy.hcl
```

I also made changed to a template which now looks something like this:

```
template {
        destination = "${NOMAD_SECRETS_DIR}/envs.txt"
        env         = true
        data        = <<EOH
{{ range nomadVarList "nomad/jobs" }}{{ . }}{{ end }}
EOH
     }
```

Now when I run the job, I get the following error while allocating:

> Killing: Template failed to read environment variables: error parsing
> env template
> "/opt/nomad/data/alloc/fe60924e-a929-39e6-7c9d-8c3c83ec2621/server/secrets/envs.txt":
> error on line 1: missing =

**EDIT 2**

Little more progress after suggestions from @KamilCuk
I made changes to a template as seen below:

```
template {
        destination = "${NOMAD_SECRETS_DIR}/envs.txt"
        env         = true
        data        = <<EOH
{{with nomadVar "nomad/jobs@arch-team" }}
    {{range $k, $v := . }}
      {{ $k }}={{ $v }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
EOH
     }
```

Looks like it is getting those key/value pair.. but there is a lot of whitespace around it as seen below:
[image]

Also When I refer to ${environment} in my `env` stanza in my task, it doesn't have that value of `dev`

Comment: You job spec is invalid, there is no task. Hm.. try just `nomadVarList "nomad/jobs"`? `it just waits and then fails.` with what message? `I am running job using my` It doesn't matter what you use to _run_ the job. The job has to have access to.

Comment: My apology for missing out task.. it was a copy/paste which did something.. What `nomadVarList "nomad/jobs` would print? All nomad jobs running? What ACL policy that I need to make sure that job has access to the variable.

Comment: I mean try `{{ range nomadVarList "nomad/jobs" }}{{ . }}{{ end }}` `All nomad jobs running?` No, it's a nomad variable, key-value store, it has nothing to do with running jobs. `What ACL` is explained in the https://developer.hashicorp.com/nomad/tutorials/variables/variables-tasks#automatic-access , but every job should have implicit access. Newer Nomad also has "Variables" tab in gui in job page you can check. With what message the allocation fails? If it stops, it just stops. I do suspect the format of `{{ . }}` is not a valid `a=b` format.

Comment: @KamilCuk, please see my `Edit 1`. I now get following error "Killing: Template failed to read environment variables: error parsing env template "/opt/nomad/data/alloc/fe60924e-a929-39e6-7c9d-8c3c83ec2621/server/secrets/envs.txt": error on line 1: missing ="

Comment: `error on line 1: missing =` Becuase `{{.}}` does not have `a=b` format. Try first with a job that does `cat secrets/envs.txt` and see the content of generated template. `error parsing env template` is about parsing the template as `env = true`, not about generating it.

Comment: When I looked at the content of envs.txt, it just has `nomad/jobs`.. So looks like it didn't get variables. It is just its path

Comment: Makes sense, that is `.`. Check https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/nomad-1-4-variable-and-iterate-over-nomadvar-elements/44358/2 . Also you are using `nomadVarList` vs `nomadVar`, no idea the difference.

Comment: @KamilCuk, I made significant progress with your suggestions. I am almost there. Please look at my Edit 2. I get the variables printed but then it has lot of whitespace as well as when I refer to `${environment}`, it gets nothing

Comment: Whitespaces are fine, you can learn about whitespace controol in go templates https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#hdr-Text_and_spaces . `well as when I refer to` I will guess most probably a typo.

Comment: I corrected the whitespace issue and now my envs.txt looks `environment=dev` But I still can't access that environment variable from my task's `env` block where I am setting `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = ${environment}` Is there anything I am missing? I am super close on masking this work. Is there any way, I can see environment variable has been set or not fore that task?

Comment: `I am setting ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = ${environment}` ? The environmnet is exported for the process, _where_ are you setting `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = ${environment}`? If you are doing that in the job spec, it will be not there. Are you accessing `${environment}` or are you accessing `${ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT}`?  `I can see environment variable has been set` The `env` or `printenv` shell commands print the environment variables exported for the process. You can run them from shell.

Comment: If you want to set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` I would typically do `{{with nomadVar "nomad/jobs"}}ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT={{.environment}}{{end}}`, using a global use everything sounds error prone and will often restart the job when unrelated configuration is edited..

Comment: @KamilCuk, Sorry for the late response. I tried your suggestion and it worked on the first go. Can you please suggest it as an answer that I can accept? I want to make sure that you get the necessary recognition and points to answer this question. I  really appreciate you stand by me and help me out resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically I use nomad variables like the following:

```
{{with nomadVar "nomad/jobs/<the_name_of_the_job>"}}
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT={{.environment}}
{{end}}
```

The `{{.}}` does not egenerate `k=v` format readable by `env=true`, but some internal Go object representation unreadable to anyone.

The `nomad/jobs` nomad variable directory should be accessible by any job, you can share your variables between all jobs within a namesapce there.